# RecyclerView within another RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a mixed items in a `RecyclerView` parent, within it, contains some `CardViews` with another `RecyclerView` inside it. If you can't see it yet, imagine several `ListViews` inside a `RecyclerView` (with the `ListViews` being grouped by a Header).

Here is a structure that I've drawn to make it more clear:

[image: RecyclerViewCeption]

Above is the layout structure that I'm trying to achieve. Please note that this is only the planning. I'm not sure if it is a good idea to have a RecyclerView within a RecyclerView.

So far, I've tried using [ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/grennis/ExpandableRecyclerView/) to achieve this kind of complex layout. But the problem is when adding a different item type in the RecyclerView (eg. a horizontal scroll carousel), it is hidden within the Header.

I can't think of any other ways now. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to achieve this layout?

To make it simple, it is a sectioned `RecyclerView` within a child `CardView` inside a `RecyclerView` parent, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Your solution is quite simple. What you need is 3 Fragments (Fragment A: RecyclerView 1) (Fragment B: RecyclerView 2 ). (Fragment C: Carousel footer ) . and three of them are independent inside one activity. Do you understand?

Comment: I can't have fixed Fragments inside the parent RecyclerView. The groups are populated from a model.

Comment: Well, I may not understand you clearly. But i remember the last time i had a layout like this. It seemed pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: The Cardviews are static , but the contents are populated from a model right?

Comment: Even the cardviews are from model. It can have more than 2 cards there. Also i want it to be able to put the carousel anywhere between the cards. Thanks for the suggestion though :-)

Comment: Easiest example I can see is how the list page in Stack Exchange app is done

Comment: oh i see, you can still achieve this with xml though, there is nothing wrong with having a RecyclerView within another RecyclerView, as far as it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a RecyclerView within another RecyclerView is discouraged. However if you want to achieve the above using nested RecyclerViews, you can use a layout manager that wraps the RecyclerView to its content's height for the innermost (Green Coloured) RecyclerView. There is one such layout manager already available at https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager

Also make sure to disable touch gestures on the innermost RecyclerView by setting an onTouchListener as follows.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try this out when I'm home

Comment: I've opted to make nested RecyclerViews instead and use the library you've suggested. Thanks, it finally worked! My implementation here: https://github.com/aimanbaharum/RecyclerViewCeption

Comment: Good to know it worked for you. A word of warning though, In your implementation, you are adding the RecyclerView ItemTouchListener in onBindViewHolder. Since views get recycled, you end up adding multiple listeners to the RecyclerView. I suggest you move the listener adding part to the ViewHolder class to increase performance. Happy coding :)

Comment: One other thing though, what is the purpose of disabling touch gesture as you've mentioned?

Comment: When touch propagation occurs on the parent recyclerview, if your child recyclerview is allowed to receive gestures, sometimes your parent recyclerview might not scroll since the child recyclerview is absorbing the scroll gestures. As a fail safe measure I added it. You can remove it if it works without it though.

Comment: @MuchOverflow Why is having a recycler view inside another discouraged?  Please explain and give alternative approaches to achieve the result other than this approach. :)

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat This answer is old. There is no need for an additional library for this now as google now has enabled wrap_content support for RecyclerView. You can nest recyclerviews by setting inner recyclerview's height to wrap_content and disabling nested scrolling by ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(innerRv, false)

Comment: @MuchOverflow Thanks a lot. :) But can I achieve touch listener for child views?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat You can add click listeners to any child views as you are only disabling scroll via the app compat interface

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet how to achieve the nested recycling?
I mean how to use view holder for the outer recycler view? Will the inner recycler view an item on the view holder of the outer recycler view?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Will the inner recycler view an item on the view holder of the outer recycler view? - Yes. 

Can you provide some code snippet how to achieve the nested recycling? - I am unavailable now. I will see if I can create a sample during this weekend

Comment: How do you avoid having `onCreateViewHolder` called for all of the items in the inner `RecyclerView` ? It doesn't seem to recycle at all now...

Comment: @androiddeveloper this was answered a while ago. I recommend using the library 'Groupie' which handles complex recyclerview layouts much more elegantly

Comment: @MuchOverflow Isn't there a more "native" way to solve this? I ask it because it might be a solution for this question I wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49257863/878126