# It is possible to display data like Map<String,ArrayList<Notes>> using recycler view? if yes than how to achieve it

Tags: android, dictionary, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a `Map<String,ArrayList<Notes>>`, in which `String` is a date and `ArrayList<Notes>` is a list of Notes(Heading, Description, AttachedFile) taken during a day. While AttachedFiles in Notes to be download onClick event.


This Map look likes

> - 01-02-2016 (2 Notes)
>        -Note 1 Heading
>        -Note 1 Description
>        -Note 1 AttachedFile
>        -Note 2 Heading
>        -Note 2 Description
>        -Note 2 AttachedFile
> - 02-02-2016 (1 Notes)
>        -Note 1 Heading
>        -Note 1 Description
>        -Note 1 AttachedFile
> - 02-02-2016 (3 Notes)
>        .............................
>        .............................

Now, I want to display these data in recycler view (using card view for Days).

Is there any other efficient way to achieve this senario?
if yes than how to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946182/recyclerview-within-another-recyclerview

Comment: Even more similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type