# RecyclerView of cardViews. Each cardview again has list of items. How can i achieve this

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to implement a UI where I have a recyclerview with multiple cardviews. Each cardview again has a list of items to be displayed. Can I achieve this UI using a single recyclerView. As far as I know it won't be a good idea to have a nested recyclerview. I want to achieve UI something like this [RecyclerView within another RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946182/recyclerview-within-another-recyclerview). Just wanted to check if it can be using a single RecyclerView. If I end up using nested recyclerview will there be any performance issues.

Thanks in advance,
Sagar

Comment: Not sure if you can do it using single recyclerView. But I have done using Nested RecyclerViews. Performance depends on size of the data. As I had few data, performance was negligible I can say.

Comment: ok my data is like 10+ items in each card and these items can also be deleted at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create put recycler view inside another
So, here is the hierarchy of view.

main.xml

```
<NestedScrollView> // as main container
  <RecyclerView/>
</NestedScrollView>
```

cardview_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
   <CardView>
     <RecyclerView/>
   </CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

cardview_recycler_item.xml

```
// btw, here you make layout for individual row design which will be inside cardview`s recyclerview.
<LinearLayout>
  // draw here
</LinearLayout>
```

As ussual you create two adapters; one for each recycler
Hope it helps, if smth is unclear please comment

Comment: Thanks Shohruh for your reply. my data is like 10+ items in each card and these items can also be deleted at runtime. Just wanted to check would it be good performance-wise as its a nested recyclerview

Comment: Yep. If u really need such hierarchy, and if u technicall it is really needed, then performance could be neglected ))))

Answer (score 0):

as i understood you want to create recyclerview with sectioned items where each item has header and list.So this [Library](https://github.com/IntruderShanky/Sectioned-RecyclerView)

will make your life easy

Comment: thanks for the reply in my case I want a single cardview which will have a header, ListView and a footer and there will be a list of such cardviews. The above library seems to be using a different card for headerview and a different card for each listItem

Comment: Any one has any other pointers for this ? Any ideas would be appreciated.